# Can I set a true/false for every entry in a single column using DynamoDB AWS console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table in DynamoDB and i'd like essentially to set a boolean to true/false for ALL rows or entries in that table, for just a single column. Let's say the column is called UserActive. I know i can do this by clicking the pencil/edit icon in the console, for each individual row, but for thousands of entries, that's just not feasible. I need to be able to do this from the AWS console.

How can i set them all to true/false in one go?

Answer (score 2):

> I need to be able to do this from the AWS console.

There is no way to edit multiple documents at once from the console. Sorry.

---

What you can do is write a script in the language of your choice using the AWS SDK to scan through all your documents and update them.

Comment: Where would such a script run? Can i run it purely from the console? When you say document, do you mean row? I have a single column, common to each row. And its in this column that i need to set all the values to true/false in one go.

Comment: You can run your script from your computer's shell console if you want, but not from the AWS console. In the non-relational database word, a "document" is the equivalent of a "row", yes.

Comment: What would i run in my local console? I use JavaScript and AWS Amplify

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html